# Using execvp with parameters

Tags: c++

I want to know how can I run a program with parameters using `fork()` and `execvp()`.

I want to run the program `test` and passed the parameter `flag`.

I am using the variable `args` to capture the string `start /test flag`. This code snippet below is contained inside a conditional statement that checks for the parsed string `start /test -flag`.

```
arguments[0] = "/test"
arguments[1] = "-flag"
```

```
                    char * arguments[3];
                    arguments[0] = (char*)args[1].c_str();
                    arguments[1] = (char*)args[2].c_str();
                    arguments[2] = NULL;
                    cout << "Arguments[1] = " << arguments[1] << endl;
                    pid_t pid = fork();
                    // ERROR
                    if (pid == -1)
                        perror("ERROR: Failed to fork");
                    // Child
                    if (pid == 0)
                    {
                        cout << "child: " << pid << endl;

                        if (execvp (arguments[0], arguments) == -1)
                        {
                            perror("exec");
                        }
                    }
                    // Parent
                    if (pid > 0)
                    {
                        wait(0);
                        cout << "parent: " << pid << endl;
                    }
```

Does this mean that my program `test` is getting passed the parameter `flag` as an argument? In other words, `ARGV[0]:` flag?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "YOU ENTERED: " << argc << "ARGUMENTS" << endl;
    cout << "ARGV[0]: " << argv[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: argv[0] is the command and argv[1] would be the first flag

Comment: I have run this code. I changed a couple of things and added a couple of cout's in the test file. argv[0] shows to be /test and argv[1] flag. Thank you.

Comment: So if you already know the answer, what question are you asking?

Comment: The convention on Unix and Linux is that the first parameter to a program is its own filename.